# failed to delete in mongodb collection with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb to store express-session [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) its work fine with insert and update but failed to delete session from collection i don't know why but it works first time when i restart my server

```
async function logout(req, res) {
 if (!req.sessionID || !req.session.adminId){
     res.send({status:400,detail:"Invalid Request"})
     return;
 }
 if (sessionStore!=null){
     sessionStore.remove({"_id":req.sessionID},true)
     res.send({status:200,detail:"Logged Out"})
 }
 else {
     res.send({status:400,detail:"Something went wrong"})
 }
}

/*sessionStore here is my collection object e.g db.collection('sessions') as below*/
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/AdminSessionDb", function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB-AdminSessionDB', err);
        return;
    }
    else {
        // console.log('Connected to MongoDB-capptinAdminSessions => auth.js');
        adminSessionsCollection = db.collection("sessions");
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried without true in your query?

Comment: yeah i tried infact i tried with deleteMany and remove function , but unfortunately failed

Comment: and when i restart server it delete fine with all the functions e.g remove,deleteOne , deleteMany ..

Comment: have you tried _id:ObjectId(your_id) in remove query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap id in ObectId() as following: db.collection.remove( {"_id": ObjectId("ID")});

```
async function logout(req, res) {

if (!req.sessionID || !req.session.adminId){
    res.send({status:400,detail:"Invalid Request"})
    return;
}
if (sessionStore!=null){
    sessionStore.remove({"_id": Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.sessionID)})
    res.send({status:200,detail:"Logged Out"})
}
else {res.send({status:400,detail:"Something went wrong"})
 }
}

/*sessionStore here is my collection object e.g db.collection('sessions') as below*/
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/AdminSessionDb", function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB-AdminSessionDB, err);
        return;
    }
    else {
        // console.log('Connected to MongoDB-capptinAdminSessions => auth.js');
        adminSessionsCollection = db.collection("sessions");
    }
});
```

Comment: my sessionId is already a string , anyhow i tried with ObjectId but it show error "  Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters "

Comment: my req.sessionId is like 2SXBWzAMq6laXsmYtLGqJHpdt3omDesG